# how to cut tax from same gift voucher in opencart?

Tags: opencart

I have a problem with opencart gift vouchers, currently when the gift vouchers is used the tax is not being deducted from the voucher, instead opencart ask the customer to pay the tax explicitly.

Actually i want to deduct the tax from that same voucher which is being used.

is it possible?

If yes, how?

Comment: To be honest, I do not get the point... Could you show us some examples with numbers?

Comment: i want a system in which tax is deducted directly from the voucher when it is been used.
For example, if i have a gift voucher of $100 and i purchase some product of $50 then the tax should be deducted from this voucher like $50 + tax from the same voucher which has been used, but now only $50 is deducted from the voucher and for the tax i have to pay it separately from my card.

Comment: OK, now I see... And are you using the default voucher logic or some extension for that?

Comment: it is opencart default voucher!